# How to use prisma from backend library in seperate api project (Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. )

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have 2 projects
project-1. Essentials (library)
It will have all database related stuff like Create, Read, Update and Delete operations.
It have prisma client(@prisma/client) which is used to communicate with database.

project-2. Api
It will use all the functions from Essentials library and only provides endpoints to those operations.
It do not require prisma client(@prisma/client) because all database stuff is happening in essentials library. But still I am getting this error while calling the api endpoint

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3001, url: http://localhost:3001
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
info  - automatically enabled Fast Refresh for 1 custom loader
event - compiled client and server successfully in 235 ms (178 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 43 ms (178 modules)
wait  - compiling /api/register...
event - compiled successfully in 22 ms (42 modules)
error - Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues
    at new PrismaClient (/home/roringo1/Desktop/antique-collection-local-2/antique-api/node_modules/.prisma/client/index.js:3:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/roringo1/Desktop/antique-collection-local-2/antique-api/node_modules/antique-essentials/build/lib/prisma.js:5:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/roringo1/Desktop/antique-collection-local-2/antique-api/node_modules/antique-essentials/build/registerAccount.js:37:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
```

(Also used next-transpile-modules, but didn't worked)

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Did you run npx prisma generate in your project-1? Prisma needs to generate types in order to work

Comment: This will pretty much all depend on your folder/workspace setup. Are you using a monorepo?